# Adding column to list in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following list :

```
Training_Frame = pca.fit_transform(np_scaled_train)
```

with the following shape `(2358,4)`
I want to add a fifth column,  This column is saved in a pandas dataframe, for that here what I've tried without any success :

```
Training_Frame.append(dataframe_train.iloc[:,-1])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

So I've tried the following

```
   saved_frame = np.append(Training_Frame,dataframe_train.iloc[:,-1])
    # This works but the result has a weird shape `(11790,)` despite :
    np.shape(dataframe_train.iloc[:,-1])  # is (2358,) so I'm expecting or hopping to get  a shape like `(2358,5)
```

`

So I kind of don't get what's the issue here, any Idea how could I do this ?

Comment: `np.append` is often misused.  Learn to use `np.concatenate` instead.

Comment: Despite its name, `Training_Frame`  is not a DataFrame; it is a numpy array. You can convert it to a DataFrame with `pd.DataFrame(Training_Frame)`.

Comment: I think you need `np.column_stack()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `Training_Frame` and `dataframe_train` are of the same length:

```
Training_Frame = np.column_stack((Training_Frame, dataframe_train.iloc[:,-1].values))
```

Alternatively you can generate a DataFrame from NDArray (as @ayhan suggested in the comments):

```
Training_Frame = pd.DataFrame(Training_Frame).assign(column_name=dataframe_train.iloc[:,-1])
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I've tried your suggestion and here's what I get : 


IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: @Engine, what is the output of `print(type(Training_Frame))`?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I still have issue understand all datatypes in python :/.  I'm using the first suggestion thanks again. I can accept ur answer in 5 min

Comment: @Engine, glad i could help :-)